# Does CSS formatting have to be different when linking from a stylesheet?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been playing around with bootstrap and at first i changed some CSS in the head section using the `<style></style>`.

I tried to link it from a stylesheet using;

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/testStyles.css">`

now my index page is all over the shop. Some of the styles look as if they work and the rest don't. Am i meant to be adding something extra before I specify what I want styled? example code of my CSS INSIDE my index page which does not work when linked.

```
body {
  font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #818181;
  }
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
h4 {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  }  
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #f4511e;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 100px 25px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  }
```

Comment: CSS formatting is the same. Check your file path

Comment: Have you cleared the bowser cache after switching to CSS files? Are you getting any errors in the browser's dev console?

Comment: Do you have any additional CSS files? If so, link your home css at the end of all your CSS file linkage